# How to set X-Frame-Options to deny?

Tags: configuration, iis

I have a recently upgraded solution, now running on Sitecore 8.1-upd3. Apparently in this version, Sitecore includes a http module to include a X-Frame-Options header, set to `SAMEORIGIN`: `<add type="Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXFrameOptionsHeaderModule" />`.

All very nice, but my customer wants it set to `DENY` for the CD servers. I checked the code from the module and the value is rather hardcoded, although there is a check not to overwrite an existing value:

```cs
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
if (!Enumerable.All<string>((IEnumerable<string>) response.Headers.AllKeys, (Func<string, bool>) (key => key != "X-Frame-Options")) || !(response.ContentType == "text/html"))
    return;
response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

What would be the best way to set this header to `DENY`? (considering maintainability, performance, effort, ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your best option (requiring no code or overwrites) would be to configure UrlRewrite to filter out the header. There are already half a dozen reasons why you might have this module installed already on your server - might as well use it.

Open up UrlRewrite for your site, and click "View Server Variables".

[image]

Then add your `X-Frame-Options` header.

Then proceed to create an `Outbound Rule` where you explicitly rewrite your `X-Frame-Options` header to `DENY` as required.

[image]

Source: [Remove Unwanted HTTP Response Headers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/)

Comment: Note that you need to specify variable name as RESPONSE_X-Frame-Options, not just X-Frame-Options and you don't need to add a "Server Variable" for this to work.

Comment: You should end up with a section like this in the web.config -        `<outboundRules>
                <rule name="X-Frame-Options" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-Frame-Options" pattern="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="DENY" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>`