# Does Sitecore add X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN?

Tags: configuration, iis

I have a Sitecore 8.1 Update-3 solution. We have some simple ASPX files that we are trying to use as part of a Facebook application. Apparently the Facebook application displays the pages in an iFrame. And apparently somehow our pages are getting the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header added to the response.  I cannot figure out where that is coming from.  And because of that header these pages cannot be displayed in a Facebook iFrame.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Is this a Sitecore issue?  Or is it something deep in IIS or the machine config or something?  It is driving me crazy. I have been able to go in to IIS and add a second X-Frame-Options header with the value of "ALLOW_FROM https://facebook.com".  But that doesn't solve the problem. That just creates 2 headers and it still won't display the page in an iFrame.

I can't figure out if this is a Sitecore problem or an IIS problem.

Comment: Answer is in this question: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-set-x-frame-options-to-deny.. not sure if that makes it a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I saw that.  It is a similar question.  But I am trying to remove the header, not just change its value.

Comment: Just remove the module from the web.config.. (but if you get a security audit they probably will tell you to put something back)

Comment: Something worth noting is even putting the ALLOW_FROM header might not work in all browsers. The simple presence of the X-Frame-Options header is enough to trigger it to only do SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's added by an HttpModule.  In the `system.webServer/modules` section of the web.config.

```xml
<add type="Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXFrameOptionsHeaderModule" />
```

Interestingly, this is appears to be new to 8.1 update 3, but it is not mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: You may also discover a duplicate entry created by the RequestForgeryToken when building forms. Check out this article to help you hide the duplicate entry. https://long2know.com/2016/03/asp-net-anti-forgery-configuration/ `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;`