# X-Frame Option in Sitecore 9

Tags: configuration, security

I have added the following `X-frame-options` header in **web.config**:

```xml
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />

    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />   

  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Despite adding this header, our security scan still recommends that anti-framing measures need to be taken. How do we implement X-Frame-options properly?

I want to set the HTTP response header with `X-frame-options` that should reflect across application, with **sameorigin**.

Please suggest that is this approach is correct or if it needs to be implemented differently in Sitecore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set X-Frame-Options to deny?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-set-x-frame-options-to-deny)

Comment: I want to set x-frame options in HTTP header .the above URL is to deny.i am trying to figure where I have to write HTTP response header to apply all over the solution

Comment: I agree the above _is a different question_ and there have been changes in the Sitecore 8.2 update-4 code that means this is not 100% correct any more.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is ***one of*** the recommended approaches to [prevent clickjacking](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/#Enabling-X-Frame-Options-Header), and adding the `X-frame-options` header is one of the required steps.

After making the changes to the web.config, you should see that `X-frame-options` should be present in the response headers.

You should also ensure that relevant [`Content Security Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) headers have also been set.

> Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement to distribution of malware.

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

I suspect this is the reason your security scan is still failing. Setting the [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) is one of the [OWASP recommendations](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet) to prevent clickjacking.

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

With these config changes in place, you should now see the following response headers being returned:

[image: Content Security Policy headers]

I recommend you check the security headers present on your website using https://securityheaders.com/ which will scan the security headers present and you can see what else you might be missing. Note that this tool can only work against a live, publicly accessible site, i.e. you can check your local website.

I also recommend reading these blog posts by [Akshay Sura](https://www.akshaysura.com/2016/08/19/secure-sitecore-secure-headers-xss-protection/) and [Bas Litjen](http://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-security-3-prevent-xss-using-content-security-policy/) which contain a number of other recommendations.

### Sitecore X-Frame-Options module

Sitecore has introduced an `X-frame-options` module, which is included by default in the `web.config` as an http module:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add type="Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXFrameOptionsHeaderModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Prior to Sitecore 8.2 Update-4, this would add an `X-frame-options='sameorigin'` header to be added to **all** requests. However a [change was made in this version](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update4/Release%20Notes) to so this header was *only* added to backend requests to the CMS (by checking that the security domain of the requested site is 'sitecore')

> 122317: The XFrameOptionsHeaderModule module picks up front-end requests.

For earlier versions, using [Outbound Rules of the URL Rewrite in IIS](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-set-x-frame-options-to-deny) is the recommended way to *change* the header. For Sitecore 8.2 onwards you *need to handle this yourself* and add the headers you require, including `X-frame-options`.

This leads to a problem that the `X-frame-options` will be inserted twice for requests to the backend admin. Options to mitigate this are:

- Only add the `customHeaders` on your CD servers
- Create a custom Http Module and add it to *web.config* modules section in a similar way that to the Sitecore `XFrameOptionsHeaderModule`, and add a check to *only* add the header if it is not already present.
- Use a slightly more advanced outbound rule to only insert the header when it is [not present using preconditions:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module#defining-a-precondition)

```xml
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add RESPONSE_X-Frame-Options" preCondition="X-Frame-Option not present">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Frame_Options" pattern=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="X-Frame-Option not present">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_X_Frame_Options}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>  
</rewrite>
```

This will insert the `X-Frame-Options` header **only** if is has not already been set, so will allow the Sitecore `XFrameOptionsHeaderModule` to insert the header for the backend and independently allow you to insert the header for your frontend/CD sites.

Comment: For Sitecore 9.3 onwards, if you will add <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" /> then Horizon site will not load Sitecore site for Editing Experience, so no need to use <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" /> from above mentioned configurations.